# Facing Force Close and the problem is in InnerClasses attribute

Tags: android

I built an API and facing a force close in it and this is the following waring that i am getting at console side.

```
[2011-02-04 17:49:05 - RMALiteTesting] warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class that doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. (This class was probably produced by a broken compiler.)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably came from a third-party JAR file that you added to your project.

If the JAR file is from an open source project, remove the JAR and add the project source code to your project. Or, create a separate project just for that source code, to build you a clean JAR using your own Java compiler.